# Working out how long a battery will last

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I'm hoping somebody can help me understand this. I use a Resmed S9 VPAP ST-A/ S9 COPD which according to documentation at my settings draws a current of 1.4A.

I use a Resmed Powerstation 2 battery. The ratings on the back say 97Wh output 24V 3.75A.

I wanted to calculate how long this battery would last. I know it lasts for around 10hrs but i'd like to know how to work it out.

I started by working out the amp hours by dividing 97 by 24 = 4.041 which I thought was the amp hours. I then divided this by 1.4 which gives me 2.8hrs which I know is not right. I'm no expert on this sort of thing and obviously missing or not understanding something. Please can somebody help! Thanks in advance

Comment: What voltage does the S9 VPAP draw its 1.4A at? If there's a DC-DC converter lurking somewhere, that would throw off your sums. Or maybe the 1.4A is a very generous maximum, or perhaps a high starting current, and the long term run current is actually much less?

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. I'm 99% sure its 24V. This is the info I got from the net. Product
Treatment pressure*
(cm H2O)
Current draw
at 12 V DC (amps)
Battery size for 8 hours use
(amp-hours) 1.4A.

Comment: Sorry I dont have anymore info

Comment: Your calculation appears right for the numbers you have given.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said, your calculation is right: 
**P=U*I***, so **Ph = U*I*h**. If you rearrange, then you get **I*h = P*h/U ~= 4Ah**. This, divided by 1.4A will give you ~2.8 hours.

There must be something wrong in the specs of your values (I think your COPD does draw less than 1.4A).

Answer (score 0):

97WH battery means it can power 97 Watt load for 1 hour at rated voltage of 24 volt. if you take lesser load which in your case is (at 1.4 A continuous) it will last  for approx 3 hours.